# question about rest-api error or my mistake

Tags: rest

I'm just a newbie in java, rest-api; so i'm trying to build a simple restful-api project used java, eclipse, and wildfly 10. The project was deployed but i cannot call the API via browser by URL. Do i have mistake or configuration has not been set ? Someone help me please, many thanks.
i am not good at english as well, so apologize if it's hard to understand

```
package it_kickstart;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/rest")
public class KickStartService {

    @GET
    @Path("/html")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHTML() {
        return "<p>JAX-WS with JBoss WildFly 10.x</p>";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        return "JAX-WS with JBoss WildFly 10.x";
    }
}
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Rest_API_1</display-name>

</web-app>
```

URL used to call : http://localhost:8080/Rest_API_1/rest/html

Comment: kindly refer this https://restfulapi.net/create-rest-apis-with-jax-rs-2-0/

Comment: already read it, but u can see, i am not use jersey, just basic rest spectification with annotation @Path, but my API was not run. It must return "<p>JAX-WS with JBoss WildFly 10.x</p>" when i type http://localhost:8080/Rest_API_1/rest/html